# example usage of CKEditor5 CodeBlock

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

i'm trying to add CodeBlock plugin into CKEditor browser version (non node.js version), the doc is only provide npm-based installation, how can i achieve this in browser-only CKEditor

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/code-blocks.html

Comment: more details please ...

Answer (score 3):

**CKEditor 5 has an online builder**. You can easily add the feature you want from this [link](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)

As CKEditor is fully written on javascript is easy for them to maintain it in Node(NPM).

All you need to build a CKEditor plugin is to choose the features you need and install those feature by **npm install** and then built it by using **Webpack** manually.

For this thing, CKEditor has an online builder where you can easily choose Editor type and features you want and press custom build.

You can easily download the Custom build and structure will look like the below image.

[image: Build Structure]

**You can find ckeditor.js file in the build folder which is what you actually asked in the question.**

You can easily find the CKEditor.js in the Src folder, which has all installed plugin configuration.

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2014-2020, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import Code from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/code.js';
import CodeBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock.js';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph.js';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table.js';

class Editor extends ClassicEditor {}

// Plugins to include in the build.
Editor.builtinPlugins = [
    Autoformat,
    BlockQuote,
    Code,
    CodeBlock,
    Essentials,
    Paragraph,
    Table
];

export default Editor;
```

Webpack Configuration file like below:

```
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2014-2020, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
 */

'use strict';

/* eslint-env node */

const path = require( 'path' );
const webpack = require( 'webpack' );
const { bundler, styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );
const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin' );
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require( 'terser-webpack-plugin' );

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    performance: { hints: false },

    entry: path.resolve( __dirname, 'src', 'ckeditor.js' ),

    output: {
        // The name under which the editor will be exported.
        library: 'ClassicEditor',

        path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'build' ),
        filename: 'ckeditor.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: 'default'
    },

    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new TerserWebpackPlugin( {
                sourceMap: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    output: {
                        // Preserve CKEditor 5 license comments.
                        comments: /^!/
                    }
                },
                extractComments: false
            } )
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new CKEditorWebpackPlugin( {
            // UI language. Language codes follow the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1 format.
            // When changing the built-in language, remember to also change it in the editor's configuration (src/ckeditor.js).
            language: 'en',
            additionalLanguages: 'all'
        } ),
        new webpack.BannerPlugin( {
            banner: bundler.getLicenseBanner(),
            raw: true
        } )
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [ 'raw-loader' ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader',
                        options: {
                            injectType: 'singletonStyleTag',
                            attributes: {
                                'data-cke': true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: styles.getPostCssConfig( {
                            themeImporter: {
                                themePath: require.resolve( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark' )
                            },
                            minify: true
                        } )
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Suppose if you want to add an additional feature you can simply build it in online or else install in npm and add the feature in CKEditor.js in src file and build the Webpack file using this command **"npx webpack --config webpack.config.js"**

But before running this command you need to install webpack and all the required npm node modules.